# Variable used in lambda should be final or effectively final

Tags: java, lambda

Есть код:

```
while (true) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i++ < ...) {
        int curr = i;
        futures.add(executor.submit(() -> {
             someMethod(curr);
        }));
    }
}
```

который отлично компилируется и работает. Однако, если убрать локальную переменную `curr`:

```
while (true) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i++ < ...) {
        futures.add(executor.submit(() -> {
             someMethod(i);
        }));
    }
}
```

компилятор выдаёт ошибку: "variable used in lambda should be final or effectively final". Можно ли как-нибудь обойти это ограничение, не создавая лишнюю локальную переменную (`curr`), или же это невозможно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет.

Запрещено это т.к. лямбда:`() -> {someMethod(i);}` буквально означает: «когда будешь выполняться возьми переменную `i` и отправь ее в `someMethod`».

На момент выполнения значение `i` многократно изменится и может быть недоступно. Во избежание неожиданных ошибок при параллельном исполнении, передачу в лямбды изменяемых переменных запретили.

Запрет и его обоснование указаны в спецификации ([JLS §15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)):

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in a lambda expression must either be declared final or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.
> ...
> Similar rules on variable use apply in the body of an inner class (§8.1.3). **The restriction to effectively final variables prohibits access to dynamically-changing local variables, whose capture would likely introduce concurrency problems.** Compared to the final restriction, it reduces the clerical burden on programmers.
>
> *Любая локальная переменная, формальный параметр или параметр исключения, использованный, но не объявленный в лямбда выражении, должен либо быть объявлен как final, либо быть фактически финальным ($4.12.4), иначе при попытке его использования генерируется ошибка времени компиляции.
>
> ...
>
> Аналогичные правила использования переменных применяются в теле внутреннего класса ($8.1.3). **Ограничения на фактически финальные переменные запрещают доступ для динамического изменения локальных переменных, фиксация которых может привести к проблемам параллельности.** По сравненнию с ограничением final это снижает ограничения для программистов.*

В качестве альтернативы, почему бы не вынести это в метод?

```
void submit(final int currentNumber) { 
    futures.add(executor.submit(() -> {
         someMethod(currentNumber);
    }));
}

...
int i = 0;
while (i++ < ...) {
     submit(i)
     ...
```

Comment: Это все задачки по js напоминает.

Answer (score 3):

нет, в лямбды надо передавать либо final либо effectively final переменные.

effectively final переменные - те переменные, которые после создания не изменяются внутри кода.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать такой пример:

```
private int start = 0;

Supplier<Integer> incrementer() {
    return () -> start++;
}
```

А такой код уже не скомпилируется:

```
  Supplier<Integer> incrementer() {
    int start = 2;
    return () -> start++;
  }
```

и такой тоже:

```
  Supplier<Integer> incrementer(int start) {
    return () -> start++;
  }
```

https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-effectively-final-local-variables

> Simply put, it's about where member variables are stored. Local variables are on the stack, but member variables are on the heap. Because we're dealing with heap memory, the compiler can guarantee that the lambda will have access to the latest value of start.

Можно ещё, например, использовать массив:

```
public int workaroundSingleThread() {
    int[] holder = new int[] { 2 };
    IntStream sums = IntStream
      .of(1, 2, 3)
      .map(val -> val + holder[0]);

    holder[0] = 0;

    return sums.sum();
}
```

**Но!** Это решение идёт как **Avoid Workarounds** и по ссылке выше пояснение:

> We could think that the stream is summing 2 to each value, but it's actually summing 0 since this is the latest value available when the lambda is executed.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае можно воспользоваться AtomicInteger.

```
while (true) {
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
    while (atomicInteger.incrementAndGet() < ...) {
        futures.add(executor.submit(() -> {
            someMethod(atomicInteger.get());
        }));
    }
}
```