# лямбда выражения в Java (часть 1)

Tags: java, static, лямбда-выражение, final, default

У меня два вопроса насчет лямбда в рамках содержимого данного видео
https://youtu.be/jHStUYP1NEg,
автор видео вряд ли очень скоро ответит, поэтому решил задать свои вопросы в том числе и здесь.
Так вот вопросы:
1) В случае функциональных интерфейсах, если там всего один метод - тогда ясно как лямбда работает, но что если там кроме этого метода также присутствуют static и/или default методы?  Я не понял как в этом случае лямбда может понять какой метод мы именно вызываем.
2) Интересно знать, почему в sout надо передать именно final переменную? (чтобы понять о чем я, надо смотреть видео с 09:12 до 11:20)

Comment: По поводу второго вопроса может быть интересно почитать [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/807606/204271).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на первый ваш вопрос (на второй Сергей в комментариях к вопросу дал ссылку почитать).

Функциональный интерфейс - интерфейс с 1 (и только одним) абстрактным методом (метод, который нужно заимплементить, то есть написать реализацию), но он может иметь сколько угодно static/default методов (главное условие - наличие только 1 абстрактного метода). Лямбда работает только с функциональными интерфейсами и берет как раз тот самый абстрактный метод.

P. S. для ответа на 2ой вопрос также почитайте effectively final (например, вот это [Variable used in lambda should be final or effectively final](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766897/variable-used-in-lambda-should-be-final-or-effectively-final))

Comment: всегда или в данном случае (в смысле при присутствии кроме одного абстрактного метода, есть еще и default\static методы) иногда лямбда не сработает  или какие то другие виды ошибок будут?

Comment: @RubenKubalyan обновил свой ответ в виду того, что Сергей удалил свой. Теперь я думаю все понятно

Comment: Ок, пожалуй теперь все понятно. Спасибо за помощь, жаль что моя репутация не позволяет голосовать "за"

Comment: @RubenKubalyan так отметьте ответ как правильный. вопрос то ваш

Comment: (сделал, но пишет это, если ничего - значит ок, проехали :) )Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan вы нажали зеленую галочку ?

Comment: Не знал, что надо нажать. Исправил свою ошибку, в смысле только что нажал.