# Что означает код while (i++ < ...)?

Tags: java, while

Что означает код в данной строке? я начинающий программист и для меня это очень странный код, такого нигде не встречал до сегодняшнего дня.

```
while (true) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i++ < ...) {//      <------ ?????
        int curr = i;
        futures.add(executor.submit(() -> {
             someMethod(curr);
        }));
    }
}
```

Пример взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/766897/190461)

Comment: Код должен текстом, а не картинкой! Тем более такой, на которой ничего на разобрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока значение `i` меньше `...` увеличивать `i` на единицу и выполнять тело цикла.

Comment: что значит "меньше ..."?       многоточие в параметрах методов должно располагаться в конце списка параметров метода, обозначает массив, и с ним должен, как мне представляется, указываться тип массива. В вопросе же сравниваются два значения через знак "<". C левой стороной сравнения понятно. А по какому правилу в правой части сравнения располагается многоточие ...? Это по прежнему массив? Разделитель? Какое значение извлекается из многоточия в этом сравнении?

Comment: @TimurVI многоточие в данном случае - это просто условие не описанное автором в вопросе, а не синтаксическая конструкция.

Comment: Благодарю, накрутил себе голову (:

Comment: Имеете ввиду, что автор кода просто не захотел написать элемент сравнения и специально такая конструкция в джава ни в каких условиях не будет работать? если ответ "да" к обеим составляющим моего вопроса... значит мой вопрос потеряет актуальность. Пожалуйста подтвердите что я правильно понял или  исправьте мое понимание, если оно ложное.

Comment: Да, автор просто написал "псевдокод",. Да, так не будет работать. Похоже на varargs, но не оно.

Comment: Ok. тогда нет больше вопросов. Я тоже перепутал ... в коде с varargs))